# Cannot create user in Keycloak with keycloak-admin-client

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

I want to use Keycloak as identity provider for my Spring Boot application but I am not able to create a new user.

I've already created a new realm in Keycloak and connected my Spring Boot application with the identity provider.

```
Keycloak kc = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
    .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/auth")
    .username("admin")
    .password("admin")
    .clientId("admin-cli")
    .authorization("authorization") // it throws 403: Unauthorized without this line 
    .realm("master")
    .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
    .build();

CredentialRepresentation passwordCred = new CredentialRepresentation();
passwordCred.setTemporary(false);
passwordCred.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
passwordCred.setValue("admin");

UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
user.setEnabled(true);
user.setUsername("username");
user.setCredentials(Collections.singletonList(passwordCred));

Response response = kc
    .realm("master")
    .users()
    .create(user);
```

The code I provided should create a new user but it does not. It does not throw an exception either.

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Whether you are getting token to access to Realm? @Gana

Comment: @Aliy What kind of token do I need? Another side note: The param of .authorization is just the string "authorization". Do I need to insert a token here?

Comment: Make sure admin user has 'mange-users' role. Also can you give us the contents of the 'response' object

Answer (score 1):

Try to close response after creating user, to make sure all data is flushed:

```
Response response = kc
.realm("admin-cli")
.users()
.create(user);    

response.close();
```

Comment: Does not change anything for me.